# Distribution of infimum of countably many random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, order-statistics

Motivated by my undergraduate class in probability, where we are learning about order statistics: say, you have a countable collection of i.i.d. random variables $X = \{X_1,X_2...\}$. Can we find the distribution of $Y$, where $Y = \inf X$? Take, for an example, $X \sim$ uniform(1,2), if needed.

Comment: The constant $1$, otherwise said, with pdf $\delta_1$...

Comment: If $F$ is the cdf of $X_1$ then the cdf of $Y$ is the indicator of ${\overline{F^{-1}((0,1])}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The random variable $Y = \inf_i X_i$ is almost surely a constant $c$, equal to the [essential infimum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_infimum_and_essential_supremum) of the common distribution of the $X_i$.  More concretely, if the $X_i$ have cdf $F$, then $Y = c = \inf\{ x : F(x) > 0\}$.

To see why, first notice that $P(Y < c) = 0$.  Next, for arbitrary $n,k$, compute the probability (in terms of $F$) that at least one of $X_1, \dots, X_n$ is less than $c+1/k$.  This provides a lower bound for $P(Y < c+1/k)$.  Now let $n \to \infty$ to find $P(Y < c+1/k)$, and let $k \to \infty$ using countable additivity.

It is possible that $c = -\infty$, in which case this proof needs some minor adjustments which I leave as an exercise.